# Are these passages speaking of the same Alexander?

Tags: 1-timothy, 2-timothy

In 1 Timothy 1:20

> 20 Among these are Hymenaeus and Alexander, whom I have handed over to
> Satan, so that they will be taught not to blaspheme.

In 2 Timothy 4:14-15

> 14 Alexander the coppersmith did me great harm; the Lord will repay
> him according to his deeds. 15 Be on guard against him yourself too,
> for he vigorously opposed our teaching.

Is 1 Timothy 1:20 speaking of the same Alexander as in 2 Timothy 4:14-15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the NT there are five people named "Alexander":

1. A son of Simon, Mark 15:21
2. A member of the High-Priestly family during NT times, Acts 4:6
3. A Jew is Ephesus involved in the riot, Acts 19:33, 34
4. An apostatized Christian, 1 Tim 1:19, 20
5. A coppersmith who did Paul "great harm", 2 Tim 4;14, 15.

Are these all separate people or are some the same?  We do not know.  It is possible that Alexander #3, #4, #5 could possibly be the same person; or just Alexander #3 = #5; or any other combination.

We do not have enough information to say.  However, the fact that Alexander #3 and Alexander #5 are both copepersmiths suggests they are the same person.

Ellicott suggests that Alexander #3, #4, &#5 are all (possibly) the same person but he is not certain.

Barnes thinks that #3 & #5 are the same person but cannot be certain.  Other commentators are similarly vague and non-committal.

Comment: Where is Alexander #3 called a coppersmith?

Comment: @ba - you are correct - I thought that #3 was a coppersmith but I am mistaken